# Axios hanging on retry

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, axios-retry

axios version 0.19.2
axios-retry version 3.1.9
also using FormData 2.5.1
using an express server

I'm trying to resend data on a failed checksum match. I'm sending a 406 from the express server. Axios appears to attempt a retry but then it hangs. If I stop the express server, the program continues with its retries. If I restart the server, axios appears to hang again.

```
    axiosRetry(axios, {
      retries: 10,
      retryDelay: (retryCount) => {
        console.log(`retry attempt ${retryCount}`);
        return retryCount * 1000;
      },
      retryCondition: (_err) => true
    })

   axios.post(
      url,
      newForm,
      {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
        }
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      Log(res);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        // do some stuff
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      Log(err)
      if (err.response) {
        if (err.response.status === 406) {
          console.log("got a 406")
        }
      }
    });
```

I am misunderstanding something about axios/axiosRetry and FormData. I had some code yesterday (gone now) that if the post request were sent while the server was down, it would retry and eventually make a "successful" post but on the express side, the request seemed to appear without a body. I was able to get that far by skipping the formData and posting the filestream itself. I don't remember how I handled the headers.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So the problem seems to have been a combination of using formData and the headers. Here is the modified request that works for this instance.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url:  url,
  headers: {formHeaders},
  data: fs.createReadStream({`${file}`})
});
```

Comment: What happens if you don't catch?

Comment: @JoshWulf There doesn't appear to be any change in activity. Still hanging on a retry until I close the server

Comment: What does the server code look like? Have you tried returning a different code to see if that changes the behaviour?

Comment: @JoshWulf `app.post('/upload/', async (req, res) => { console.log(req); let sampleFile = req.files.attachment; if (sampleFile.md5 != req.body.checksum) {res.sendStatus(406)} else {res.sendStatus(200)}} })` Not sure if all the braces are there. I've tried returning different codes, but it's the same each time - show a single request on the server side and show a single retry on the client side